# Issue Posting data

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, post

I am trying to post the `name="pricetag"` and `name="size"` which is in the item and price... I know this is not working because I have use echo but nothing is coming out but if I echo the pid of the product I shows. The codes below

```
<form id="add2cart" name="cart" method="Post" action="<?php fetchdir($bpages); ?>cart.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="160">Price:</td>
            <td name="pricetag" id="pricetag">£25.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="160">Item:</td>
            <td name="size" id="item">12 inch</td>
        </tr>           
        <tr>
            <td width="160">Length*:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="length" onChange="addCharge(this, this.selectedIndex);" id="priceDropDown" class="small">
                    <option value="£25.00">12 inch</option>
                    <option value="£30.00">14 inch (+£30.00)</option>
                    <option value="£35.00">16 inch (+£35.00)</option>
                    <option value="£40.00">18 inch (+£40.00)</option>
                    <option value="£45.00">20 inch (+£45.00)</option>
                    <option value="£55.00">22 inch (+£55.00)</option>
                    <option value="£60.00">24 inch (+£60.00)</option>
                    <option value="£70.00">26 inch (+£70.00)</option>
                    <option value="£80.00">28 inch (+£80.00)</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Qty" id="Qty" value="1" style="width: 20px; text-align: right" /></td>

        </tr>       
    </table>    
    <div class="cleaner h20"></div>

    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
    <input type="Submit" class="button" name="button" id="button" value="Add to shopping cart"/>
</form>
```

click here for live code http://jsfiddle.net/J4rXX/5/ by Ghillied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only information that is posted to the server from a HTML form are elements such as INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA.

If you want to post additional data, but make it un-editable to the user, you need to ideally put the data into INPUT elements which have the attributes `type="hidden"`. This will post the data from the field but make them hidden to the user posting the form.

Adding the elements anywhere in the form will work. I've positioned them at the bottom of the form element, with the already existing hidden field, in this snippet.

I've also removed the name attributes from the TD elements in the snippet, to conform with web standards.

```
<form id="add2cart" name="cart" method="Post" action="<?php fetchdir($bpages); ?>cart.php">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="160">Price:</td>
      <td id="pricetag">£25.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="160">Item:</td>
      <td id="item">12 inch</td>
    </tr>           
    <tr>
      <td width="160">Length*:</td>
      <td>
      <select name="length" onChange="addCharge(this,this.selectedIndex);" id="priceDropDown" class="small">
        <option value="£25.00">12 inch</option>
        <option value="£30.00">14 inch (+£30.00)</option>
        <option value="£35.00">16 inch (+£35.00)</option>
        <option value="£40.00">18 inch (+£40.00)</option>
        <option value="£45.00">20 inch (+£45.00)</option>
        <option value="£55.00">22 inch (+£55.00)</option>
        <option value="£60.00">24 inch (+£60.00)</option>
        <option value="£70.00">26 inch (+£70.00)</option>
        <option value="£80.00">28 inch (+£80.00)</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Qty" id="Qty" value="1" style="width: 20px; text-align: right" /></td>
    </tr>       
  </table>    
  <div class="cleaner h20"></div>

  <input type="hidden" name="pricetag" value="£25.00" id="hiddenpricetag" />
  <input type="hidden" name="size" value="12 inch" id="hiddensize" />
  <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
  <input type="Submit" class="button" name="button" id="button" value="Add to shopping cart"/>
</form>
```

EDIT:

Just noticed that the form uses javascript, upon the change of the SELECT data, to change the TD elements HTML data.

To make sure that the form posted the correct data that is in the TD elements, you would need to add ID tags to the hidden input fields so that you can program the javascript to update these as well as the TD elements.

I've added the IDs `hiddenpricetag` and `hiddensize` to the two hidden fields.

Your javascript function should be somewhat like this:

```
function addCharge(select, elemIndex)
{
    var item = select.getElementsByTagName('option')[elemIndex];
    var price = document.getElementById('pricetag');
    var sizeDOM = document.getElementById('item');

    var hiddenpricetag = document.getElementById('hiddenpricetag');
    var hiddensize = document.getElementById('hiddensize');

    var finalPrice = "";

    /* Getting the price and showing it up */
    finalPrice = parseFloat(item.text.substring(11, item.text.length-1));

    /* We set a default £25.00 value */
    if(isNaN(finalPrice)) finalPrice = "25";

    /* we add decimal */
    price.innerHTML="£"+finalPrice+".00";

    /* Getting the size and showing it up */
    var size = item.text.substring(0,7);
    sizeDOM.innerHTML = size;

    /* Altering the hidden field values */
    hiddenpricetag.setAttribute("value", "£"+finalPrice+".00");
    hiddensize.setAttribute("value", size);
}
```

JSFiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/J4rXX/7/

Comment: the value of £25.00 and the value of 12 inch changing depending on the inch choose please look at the live demo

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't POST because forms don't submit contents from TD elements. Only from INPUTs, SELECTs and TEXTAREAs.

More information on HTML FORMs [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp). If you want to avoid displaying the same data twice, you should try [INPUT type=hidden](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp).

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Pricetag</td><td>PRICE_HERE</td>
</tr>
</table>
<form>
   <input type="hidden" name="pricetag" value="PRICE_HERE" />
...
</form>
```

This should do nothing to hurt your existing JS scripts.

Comment: No matter how deep you nest that into, it won't.
You need to put that data into INPUTs. Maybe INPUT type=hidden can be your friend here, if you want to avoid displaying data twice.

Comment: The other way, of course, is using AJAX. But that also adds complexity.

Comment: The best way is ajax because I found out that someone can change the value to 0 or anything and submit the form and the price will be 0 meaning they can buy it for free so I am trying a new method which is to fetch the length from the database and also price then call the database to change the price based on the selected length.